# choosing a refurbished ultrabook for ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, hardware, web-development

I m a it student in sri lanka  with new laptops prices hiking up here i turned to refurbish laptops and also beacause stupid sizes of software i need to download For windows i turned to ubuntu. Again prices of internet here :(

For about 200$ i can get one of following ultrabooks. Help me choose one.

Samsung Ativ ultrabook 9
13. 3 display
i5 4200u
8Gb ram
256 Ssd

Dell lattitude e7440
14 Display 
i5 4200u
8Gb
500Gb hdd

Which one should i get for development in ubuntu(java python c# and php javaScript)?  and mainly for web development.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say go for Latitude, I work with those and have them running Ubuntu 18 at the moment and planing on moving to Ubuntu 20 from June-July but I never had problem with the latitudes and also they are very easy to repair if something does go wrong (with a screwdriver and instructions you can change every single part in those) Also I believe it would run perfectly fine on the one you are looking at but also you can upgrade the HDD to SSD which makes huge difference and I am not sure about the cost in Sri Lanka but SSD's are no longer that expensive.

Comment: Thanks i'll get the lattitude then. Only problem keeping me getting it is the battery time reviews on internet and i can get the ssd not expensive here too.

Comment: Unfortunately the battery life like you say its not great 3-4 hours tops especially for a refurbish laptop unless they've put a new battery in (although we use the laptops mostly on docks so we don't notice it) But again like I said I would rather go for that one in my opinion as its very nice and easy to fix and feels like a solid laptop. Also brand new battery for it in UK costs 75 pounds so its not too bad. If you go for the SSD I would recommend Crucial MX500 as they are relatively cheap while still offering similar specs to Samsung Evo's (you wouldn't notice much difference between them

Comment: Thanks for the advice. but Here in sri Lanka its smasung or kingston.  Cheapest is brand knows as lexar.  But I'll get the kingston in middle.